# Using fields in a document for another query

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections, one called Timeline and one called Posts. The first one is very simple, having 2 fields: 'PostId' and 'OwnerId', while the second one is a little bit more complex but it is not important for the purpose of my question.
Using 'OwnerId' and 'PostId' I can get a specified post in the collection Posts.

What I want to do is getting all the docs in timeline of a specified user, for each doc use it to get the post infos in Posts collection, and order the posts in descending timestamp, but I can't find a smart and effective way to do so.

To get all the docs of a specified user in Timeline I write:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await timelineRef
    .doc(currentUserID)
    .collection('timelinePosts')
    .get();
```

And to get a specified post from Posts collection I write:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await postsRef
    .doc(ownerId)
    .collection('userPosts')
    .doc(postId)
    .get();
```

How can I mix these two to get the result I want? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I found a solution that is not very elegant but at least is working:

```
QuerySnapshot snapshot = await timelineRef
    .doc(widget.currentUser.userID)
    .collection('timelinePosts')
    .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
    .get();

List<TimelineItem> timelineItems =
    snapshot.docs.map((doc) => TimelineItem.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
List<PostWidget> postsTemp = [];

for (var element in timelineItems) {
  DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await postsRef
      .doc(element.ownerId)
      .collection('userPosts')
      .doc(element.postId)
      .get();

  postsTemp.add(PostWidget(Post.fromDocument(documentSnapshot)));
}
```

I added timestamp field to my timelinePosts, created a class to contain the data from the first query, and then I did a second query based on the parameters I got on the first one for each doc.
Hopefully I'll find a more efficient solution but at the moment I use this

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a server-side join in Firestore, nor is there a way to filter the documents returned based on information in documents in another collection. All Firestore queries can do is evaluate the literal data in the candidate documents (through an index) and filter based on that.

So you will either have to duplicate the data to filter on in each `userPosts` document, or perform a so-called client-side join - with the latter being the most reasonable option for this use-case as far as I can see.

You'll end up with individual `get()` calls for the documents, or a bunch in [`in` queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) on the `FieldPath.documentId()` you get from `timelinePosts`, and then merge the results in your application code.